# How to access Facebook's personal message in messenger using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am reading about Facebook's Graph API and wondering if i can use page access token to access/read  messages sent to my personal account? And if it's a no, Please tell me how to access.

Comment: No, you can not use a page token to access anything on a user profile. And you can not access a user’s messages at all any more via API.

Answer (score -1):

You can access Facebook Page messages with the conversations endpoint: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v4.0/conversation

Comment: I am sorry, can i acess messages that sent to my personal account?

Comment: did you test the conversations endpoint? that is the only way. you cannot get user messages of personal accounts, you can only access page conversations.

Comment: Thanks @andyrandy your comment here was actually really helpful to me as I've just spent the last couple hours trying to figure out how/if I could read messages to my personal facebook account (technically group chat messages). Your comment here is really helpful to know that I can't.

Comment: Yeah, the linked pages states "_A Messenger conversation between a person and a Facebook Page or an Instagram Professional Account_"